# Golang: How do you use a pointer on a struct that hasn't been initialized yet

Tags: go

So I was looking at the [file here](https://github.com/jadekler/git-go-websiteskeleton/blob/master/app/common/access.go).

They call `record := &accessLog` but they don't ever Initialize it as a variable first and if they do it that way if there are multiple simultaneous connections is there a possibility record will get over written with somebody else's data?

```
type accessLog struct {
ip, method, uri, protocol, host     string
elapsedTime                         time.Duration
}

func LogAccess(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, duration time.Duration) {
clientIP := req.RemoteAddr

if colon := strings.LastIndex(clientIP, ":"); colon != -1 {
    clientIP = clientIP[:colon]
}

record := &accessLog{
    ip:             clientIP,
    method:         req.Method,
    uri:            req.RequestURI,
    protocol:       req.Proto,
    host:           req.Host,
    elapsedTime:    duration,
}

writeAccessLog(record)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go is a [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) language. The struct the pointer is pointing to will be valid as long as there's a reference to it. Multiple connections have nothing to do with this, as this creates a new `record` every time `LogAccess` is called, and if you follow the code in question you'll see that the reference lives at least to the end of `writeAccessLog`, possibly longer depending on the implementation of `glog.Infoln`.

To be clear `&someType { ... fields ...}` creates a new (unnamed) instance of `someType`, and then returns the address of that instance.